# Oracle Query Help - Using TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have used this type of functionality before but is MSSQL but can't get it to work for Oracle, any tips?

```
DECLARE
    MY_TBL NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN

    IF(MY_TBL > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM MY_TBL ORDER BY MY_TBL_ID DESC;
    END IF;
END;
```

What I would like to have is a flag variable set to zero or one, if one display the results, if zero skip. This is just a simple script to have all my tables and select statements in one script ans flag the ones I need to see the results for. So if I have 5 tables I would use the ELSIF function to add more like this

```
DECLARE
    MY_TBL1 NUMBER := 1;
    MY_TBL2 NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN

    IF(MY_TBL1 > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM MY_TBL1 ORDER BY MY_TBL1_ID DESC;
    ELSIF(MY_TBL2 > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM MY_TBL2 ORDER BY MY_TBL2_ID DESC;
    END IF;
END;
```

and so on. Thanks for any help on this,
--Phill

EDIT:

Here is what I have:

```
VAR result_set REFCURSOR

DECLARE
   my_tbl_1 NUMBER := 1;
   my_tbl_2 NUMBER := 0;
   my_tbl_3 NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   IF (my_tbl_1 > 0)
   THEN
      BEGIN
         OPEN :result_set FOR
            SELECT   *
                FROM my_tbl_1
            ORDER BY my_tbl_1_id DESC;
      END;
   ELSIF (my_tbl_2 > 0)
   THEN
      BEGIN
         OPEN :result_set FOR
            SELECT   *
                FROM my_tbl_2
            ORDER BY my_tbl_2_id DESC;
      END;
   ELSIF (my_tbl_3 > 0)
   THEN
      BEGIN
         OPEN :result_set FOR
            SELECT   *
                FROM my_tbl_3
            ORDER BY my_tbl_3_id DESC;
      END;
   END IF;
END;

PRINT result_set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Oracle` cannot return resultsets from a stored procedure as `SQL Server` does.

Declare cliend side cursor variables and return to them:

To display a cursor in `SQL*Plus`:

```
VAR cur1 REFCURSOR

DECLARE
        MY_TBL1 NUMBER := 1;
        MY_TBL2 NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN
        IF(MY_TBL1 > 0) THEN
        BEGIN
                OPEN :cur1
                FOR
                SELECT  *
                FROM    MY_TBL1
                ORDER BY
                        MY_TBL1_ID DESC;
        END;
        ELSIF (MY_TBL2 > 0) THEN
        BEGIN
                OPEN :cur1
                FOR
                SELECT  *
                FROM    MY_TBL2
                ORDER   BY
                        MY_TBL2_ID DESC;
        END;
        END IF;
END;
/

PRINT cur
```

Comment: I was looking at the CURSOR but does it display to the screen?

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? Variables do not display on the screen, the client applications do. In `SQL*Plus`, you can declare a `CURSOR` variable and `PRINT` it.

Comment: Tried your method and still getting an error, Does the VAR cur1 REFCURSOR need to be before the DECLARE? and PRINT outside of the END? what about / is this a typo?

Comment: @Phill: what client application do you use?

Comment: toad for Oracle version 9.6.1

Comment: it's asking for the VAR data type, I have tried a couple of different types but they all give an error

Comment: `@Phill`: Oracle cannot return a resultset right out of the procedure. You can create a `PIPELINE` function, but you won't be able to use any `DML` in it. You need find TOAD's equivalents of two things: declaring a cursor variable (`VAR cur1 REFCURSOR` in `SQL*Plus`) and fetching it ('PRINT cur')

Comment: I don't have `TOAD` installed, so can't help you it this, sorry.

Comment: I also can use DBVisulaizer (free version)

Comment: @Phill Pafford, Why don't you start SQL PLUS?

Comment: `@Phill`: it's a command line query tool for `Oracle`, bundled with every installation. `%ORACLE_HOME%/bin/sqlplus.exe` on `Windows`, `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus` on `Unix`.

Comment: The BEGIN/END are unnecessary in the IF/ELSE statement.  You only need a single BEGIN/END pair to represent the body of the sproc.  Also, you closed the sproc with END; / - this will probably give an error, it should be ";" or "/" not both.

Comment: `@rexem`: begin/end are unnecessary indeed, but I prefer using them (to add additional statements if needed). As for trailing `/`, `SQL*Plus` requires it to send the `SQL` buffer to the server. You need both `;` and `/`